# monitor new mail with label X and import mail contents to specific spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets

I'm new to google apps script. I want to script that waits for new gmail mail with a label X and then imports the mail contents to a specific spreadsheet.

The first step of monitoring email with a certain label is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857494/import-emails-that-fit-criteria-to-google-spreadsheet-using-apps-script).

Help me with the next step. What command do I need to use to target a specific spreadsheet to send the content to?

The linked code contains this command but with no targetting of a specific spreadsheet `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)) Apps script documentation is very good. You'll find it's very easy to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. And yes it is good, I was only a bit overwhelmed first and needed a little push into it.