# Type Error: Cannot read property "length" from undefined in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror

I'm trying to use @serge 's [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857494/import-emails-that-fit-criteria-to-google-spreadsheet-using-apps-script?lq=1) to pull emails into a spreadsheet.

I'm getting a type error: "Cannot read property "length" from undefined".

Any help figuring out the problem would be much appreciated.

```
function getMessagesWithLabel() {
    var destArray = new Array();
    var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('CDC Health Alerts').getThreads(1,30);

    for(var n in threads){
        var msg = threads[n].getMessages();
        var destArrayRow = new Array();
        destArrayRow.push('thread has '+threads[n].getMessageCount()+' messages');
        for(var m in msg){
            destArrayRow.push(msg[m].getSubject());
        }
        destArray.push(destArrayRow);
    }
    Logger.log(destArray);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    if(ss.getLastRow()==0){
        sh.getRange(1,1).setValue('getMessagesWithLabel() RESULTS')
    };
    sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,destArray.length,destArray[0].length).setValues(destArray)
}
```

Comment: Please check the exception stacktrace for the line the error happened on and make clear which line of your the above code snippet this is

Answer (score 0):

The only line that the `length()` property is used on, is the very last line.

```
sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,destArray.length,destArray[0].length).setValues(destArray)
```

So the array named **destArray** is not getting any data pushed into it.  If you check the value that `destArray` has in it, it will show a value of **undefined**.  You will need to start at the top of the code, and check critical points for what is getting assigned to variables.  For example:

```
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('CDC Health Alerts').getThreads(1,30);
Logger.log('threads: ' + threads);
```

Note the Logger.log() statement in the above code.  Add a `Logger.log('Some Text: ' + variableName);` statement, then VIEW the LOGS, and see if the variable 'threads` is getting what is needed assigned to it.

Keep doing this until you find a problem.  Even though the error is coming from the last line, there is an error higher up in the code, because the variable `destArray` is not getting assigned values.