# TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, typeerror, undefined

I am trying to use the code below that i got from this link:

[Import emails that fit criteria to Google Spreadsheet using apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857494/import-emails-that-fit-criteria-to-google-spreadsheet-using-apps-script/13509206#13509206)

and it is giving me the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.

Can someone help?

```
   function getMessagesWithLabel() {
     var destArray = new Array();
      var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Facebook').getThreads(1,10);

      for(var n in threads){
            var msg = threads[n].getMessages();
            var destArrayRow = new Array();
            destArrayRow.push('thread has '+threads[n].getMessageCount()+' messages');
              for(var m in msg){
                         destArrayRow.push(msg[m].getSubject());
               }
      destArray.push(destArrayRow);           
            }
    Logger.log(destArray);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    if(ss.getLastRow()==0){sh.getRange(1,1).setValue('getMessagesWithLabel() RESULTS')};
    sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,destArray.length,destArray[0].length).setValues(destArray)
    }
```

Comment: If `threads` is empty (because `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName` has an empty result, then `destArray` will be empty, and `destArray[0]` will be non-existant (undefined). You'll want to check whether `threads` is not empty before proceeding.

Comment: Other people have used this code by only changing the label name. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: getUserLabelByName('Facebook').  do your Gmail labels include Facebook?

Comment: I found out the problem var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Facebook').getThreads(1,10)    should be    var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Facebook').getThreads(0,10)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if there are no elements in `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Facebook').getThreads(1,10);` then `threads` will be null and the loop `for(var n in threads)` will not work

this means that you need to type

```
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Facebook').getThreads(1,10);

if (threads != null) {
  for(var n in threads) {
```