# Export specified e-mail body to google sheets using Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, gmail

I am trying to build a script using Google Apps Script that would identify specified messages in my inbox and transfer their body content into google sheets.

I've been trying all day to get it to work (beginner) and referred previously to [this solution][1] as well as many others but I still can't get it to work they way I want it to.

Below, some code I came up with thus far.

Basically I want it to:

- notice incoming e-mails from the specified label
- copy the specified e-mail's (sender/subject line) body into an empty row in google sheets
- move e-mail to trash
- repeat for the next e-mail and paste the body into the row below the previous one.

At the moment the function process1(message) doesn't work as the command appendRow(body) is not recognised.

Your feedback is appreciated.

Thank you.

```
        function getemails() {

    /* This enables the script to access the specified label, in this case "Your Chosen Label" */



var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Your Chosen Label");
 var threads = label.getThreads();

         for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) { 

     var messages=threads[i].getMessages();  

         for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {

             /*this, tells the script what subject lines I am after: */

       var message=messages[j];
       var subject = message.getSubject();
           if(subject=="Your chosen Subject Line")
               process1(message);
     }
     }
       function process1(message) {

     var body =message.getBody();
     var id = "Spreadsheet ID";
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
     var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
     sheet.appendRow(body);
     deleteMessage(message);           
    }  

    function deleteMessage(message){
     message.moveToTrash();
    }


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857494/import-emails-that-fit-criteria-to-google-spreadsheet-using-apps-script
```

Answer (score 0):

see the official docs for appendRow. it doesnt take a string parameter, it takes an array of elements. so if you pass instead [body] it will work. better yet pass something like [date,from,subject, body, label]

Comment: Thanks Zig it works now, and you're right it's better to pass something like [date,from,subject,body,label] etc. but first of all I don't have a good grasp of the regular expression to describe it in the script and second of all I am not sure how I would then allocate each of those to a specified column in Google Sheets. Hopefully what I managed to complet so far (with your help) will work for now. Thank you once again! Best Kam